# How to get characters like š č ć đ ž in xml and flash to appear on website?

Tags: xml, flash, special-characters, font-embedding

I have flash template which pulls text informations from xml file and have been struggling for few days now to get those characters to appear and no luck.

I have read on internet various instructions but i just can't get them to appear on website.

According to various instructions on internet in all xml and php files in template i converted text to utf-8 and set on top of the xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

and i opened all template .fla files in adobe flash cs6, went to text > font embedding and added characters that i want to embed.

So i have aboutus.xml file which is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <xml>
      <content>
           <description><![CDATA[<font color="#999999" size="300">Dobrodošli!</font>]]> </description>
      </content>
   </xml>
```

and it's loaded from aboutus.fla file and š font is missing, so it shows Dobrodoli!

But still no luck. Any help ?

Answer (score -1):

You might try using html entities, like: &scaron; for š, &ccaron; for č, etc. For the list of html entities, please see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: so if i use this i would have like Dobrodo&scaron;li in my xml file? i tried like this and not working, i also tried someone suggestion like &#353; which should be š i think but not working also.

Comment: ok, ill see with another server, i have read that server must support special characters also, im uploading files to other server now.

Comment: Still nothing, where do i put this? is it like this <![CDATA[<font color="#999999" size="300">Dobrodo&scaron;li!</font>]]>

Comment: Yes, like that. What is the actual output that you get? Btw, if your font does not have that letter implemented, then there isn't much you can do to fix it other than to open your font's file in a font editor and adding those special characters yourself. Try another font, just to make sure that your XML file is correct.

Comment: I have found solution, problem was that theme was made in flash 8, and i was editing in flash cs6 so when i published with changes something messed up, so i set flash player 8 in publish settings and now it's working.